# handler.postDelayed() not working

Tags: android

I want to repeat execution of some codes after a delay. Following is the code.

```
public void hintrun(int i){
     Handler handler = new Handler();       
     for(int j = 1; j< i+1;j++) {
         handler.postDelayed(new Runna(j), 1000); 
     }
}

class Runna implements Runnable { 
    private int j;
    public Runna(int j2) {
        j=j2;
    }

    public void run() {  
        // some code
    }
}
```

But it is not working. If say the `for` loop runs 3 times, then the code is run three times immediately after 1000 ms. I want a gap of 1000 ms between each execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your code of loop this way,

```
for(int j = 1; j< i+1;j++)
{
    handler.postDelayed(new Runna(j), 1000*j); // 1000 * J
}
```

Answer (score 1):

then replace

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runna(j), 1000);
```

with

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runna(j), 1000*(i+1));
```

Comment: this does not help. also, u r just changing delay period

Comment: well yes, first will run after 1 second, second one will run after 2 seconds, etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gap between each execution of Runna. You will need to increment the time you are delaying.

e.g.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runna(j),1000 * j);
```